# Is it possible to do conditional highlighting in vim based on whether the background color is light or dark?

Tags: linux, vim

Consider the following syntax rule, which will change any line that starts with `>>` to `Yellow` in the terminal.

```
syntax match completed /^>>.*/ 
highlight completed ctermfg=Yellow
```

The color `Yellow` shows up great on a dark (Black) background, but shows up poorly on a light (White) background.

**Is it possible to automatically switch to a different color when the background is a light color?**

I have looked through `:help highlight`, but I have not found any direct way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Kent does not work if you put your code directly into `.vimrc`, because by the time `.vimrc` is processed, `background` is not set yet. You can execute the command after the syntax rules have been set by:

```
au Syntax * call SetSyntax()

function SetSyntax()
    if &background == "dark"
        " dark theme
    else
        " light theme
    endif
    set cursorline
endfunction
```

Comment: I had to use `au OptionSet background call…` to make it work (Vim 8.1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set the option `background`, you could try something like:

```
exec "hi! completed ctermfg=".(&background=='dark'?'yellow':'black')
```

Comment: I am assuming that the background is set externally to vim, in the terminal itself. I am currently on `gnome-terminal` but it would be nice to generalize.

Comment: Moreover, I just realized `set background` returns `light` even though the blackground is black.

Comment: @merlin2011 it depends on the colorscheme. E.g. you set your terminal bg as black, but the colorscheme can set the bg of vim (`Normal`) with white. but you are right, checking the `background` option is not always correct to decide the bg dark/light

Comment: @merlin2011 yes, usually a dark/light colorscheme will recommend you to set the `background` with corresponding value.  see `:h 'bg'`  If the colorscheme doesn't set the `ctermbg`, it will use the terminal bgcolor, then it is hard to get the value...

Comment: @merlin2011 think about these two alternatives: define your `completed` group with a dark bgcolor?  2) write a function toggle the `completed` fgcolor between yellow and black, with a shortkey? so that you can change it easily if the dark/light bg doesn't fit your highlighting

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will play with it and add a comment.